# VBA Loop: Copy Range from Multiple Worksheets to Multiple Set Locations

Tags: vba, loops

I initially used the code (below) to compile data from 15 worksheets into a "template" sheet.  It does this very well-- however, the needs of the workbook have changed somewhat.

Rather than copying this data into a relative location (the first empty cell in "template" column A), I now need to arrange the data into set locations, offset by 25 on each loop.

Ex:

```
wks 1 copy to A3 / 
wks 2 copy to A28 / 
wks 3 copy to A53 / etc
```

I have been trying to troubleshoot, but I'm still very weak when it comes to loops.  Can anyone help me out?

```vb
Sub test()
  Dim wks As Worksheet

  For Each wks In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

    If Not wks.Name = "template" Then
      wks.Range("B6:B30").Copy
      ActiveSheet.Paste
      Destination:=Worksheets("template").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)

    End If

  Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Assume the copied data is never more than 24 rows?

```
Sub test()

Dim wks As Worksheet, r As Range

Set r = Worksheets("template").Range("A3") 'initial paste range

For Each wks In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If Not wks.Name = "template" Then
        wks.Range("B6:B30").Copy r
        Set r = r.Offset(25)                'move down 25 
    End If
Next

End Sub
```